pd.melt running successfully on python 3.9 but failing on 3.7
So, I have this code using pandas.melt():
for idx in range(len(data_rows[0])):
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    data_fields = [row[idx] for row in data_rows]
    melted_dfs.append(pd.melt(df, id_vars=key_fields, value_vars=data_fields, var_name='variable' + str(idx), value_name=column_names[idx][0]))

There is one column common in id_vars and value_vars.
id_vars=['first_name', 'last_name']
value_vars=['math_score', 'chemistry_score', 'last_name']

The interesting thing is that when I run this piece of code with python 3.9 and pandas 1.5.3, it works fine. However, with python 3.7 and pandas 1.1.5 it's giving me this error:
ValueError: arrays must all be same length

There many be any number of common columns in id_vars and value_vars. How can I make it run on python 3.7? (Please note that I cannot change the Python 3.7 configuration.)

Is the version of pandas different in your Python 3.7 and 3.9 setup?

pandas versions - on 3.9 - 1.5.3, on 3.7-1.1.5. Basically 3.7 version is used internally by Dataiku which I couldn't change.

Please edit the question and provide the complete stack trace.

Also, this code is not reproducible since it's missing the imports and setups for us to run on our own computers. Please create a Minimum Reproducible Example and update the question with it.

@joanis Updated the code and sample file

OK, reproduced. With pandas 1.1.5 I get the same error, while with pandas 1.3.5 (still python 3.7), it works. So clearly this is due to a change in pandas. If you're able to update pandas, that might be simplest. If not, you should install pandas 1.1.5 in your Python 3.9 environment so that you're writing to the same version used by Dataiku.

@joanis Thanks for your time. But what is workaround this issue.

I've just spent a while trying to find a solution, but I don't know how to fix it. As written, your code requires pandas>=1.3.0. I'm still looking for a solution, but I won't spend much longer if I don't find soon.

With pandas<1.3, I can make the error go away if I remove the third element in your data_rows, but I still don't really understand why.

Found it! The problem is that with pandas < 1.3, there is a bug that makes pd.melt() raise the error you get when there is a value in common between id_vars and value_vars. With pandas 1.3, that bug was fixed by removing the extra value from value_vars, thus pretending it was not there.

@joanis Thanks man. But what should I change in code.

I worked it out completely now, see my answer.

I was able to reproduce your error with pandas < 1.3.
The problem is that pd.melt() does not allow a variable name to be both in id_vars and value_vars. Logically, that makes sense: the same column cannnot be both identifier and value to unpivot at the same time.
With pandas >= 1.3, pd.melt() simply removes the values in value_vars that are also in id_vars, but with pands < 1.3 this input causes the error you see.
If you need to run your code with pandas < 1.3, you'll need to remove that duplicate yourself. In the reproducible code your edited in (but removed since), you can replace "last_name" in data_rows by "[none]", or else you can add this line of code before calling pd.melt() to remove the overlapping variables first:
data_fields = [field for field in data_fields if field not in key_fields]

PS: I think it's a logical error that you're trying to unpivot with last_name as both identifier and value, you should probably rethink your code to avoid getting there in the first place.
PPS: As you continue this project, I recommend you install pandas 1.1.5 in your Python 3.9 environment, so you're developing with the same library version as in your Python 3.7 environment.
